# Hair Render looks totally different in RenderViewport and the actual Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

Can anyone help me with the Hair rendering ?
Somehow the Hair Render that i have set-up looks totally different in RenderViewport and in the actual Render.

I have attached the Images and the blend file to make it clearer.
Here is the link to the Post in blenderArtist and the ***.blend**
https://blenderartists.org/t/hair-render-looks-totally-different-in-renderviewport-and-the-actual-render/1181751

The ViewPort ( the result that I wanted to have)
[image]

The actual finish Rendered (… .TT_TT…)[image: l]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your amount of children particles is set to 1 for the render, increase it to match the display (viewport).

[image]

Comment: Oh my..., such a small detail yet deadlyy......
Thank youuu Rc12